# Gettting error in SQL Server "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a SQL query, I tried very hard but still not succeeding; when I run the query, I get an error:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to it is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Here is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE [e]
SET [e].[PayerType] = IIF([p].[payer_type] = 1, 'Ep', 'NonEp'),
    [e].[LUPAAlert] = IIF(([p].[payer_type]) <> '1', 0, IIF([EpEnd] <= GETDATE(), 0, IIF([TotVisits] < 5, 1, 0))),
    [e].[LUPADays] = IIF((IIF(([p].[payer_type]) <> '1', 0, IIF([EpEnd] <= GETDATE(), 0, IIF([TotVisits] < 5, 1, 0)))) = 0, 0, CAST(EpEnd as datetime) - GETDATE()),
    [e].[FinalAlert] = IIF(([p].[payer_type]) <> '1', 0, IIF(ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpEnd])) > 1, 0, 1)),
    [e].[FinalDays] = IIF((IIF(([p].[payer_type]) <> '1', 0, IIF(ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpEnd])) > 1, 0, 1))) = 1, ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpEnd])), 0),
    [e].[RAPAlert] = IIF([p].[payer_type] = '1', IIF(ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpStart])) > 0, 1, 0), 0),
    [e].[RAPDays] = IIF((IIF([p].[payer_type] = '1', IIF(ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpStart])) > 0, 1, 0), 0)) = 1, ABS(DATEDIFF([millisecond], GETDATE(), [EpStart])), 0)
FROM 
    [tb_Episode] AS [e]
LEFT JOIN 
    [tb_Payer] AS [p] ON ([e].[CustID] = [p].[company_id])
                          AND ([e].[PayorType] = [p].[payor_type])
LEFT JOIN 
    [tb_HHPPS] AS [h] ON [e].[HHPPS] = [h].[HHPPS]
WHERE 
    [e].[billed_flag] = '0';
```

Can anyone please, help to solve this problem?

Comment: well you are using a function called datediff that requires two dates.  fairly sure the problem is one of the values you are passing to that function is not of type date.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan, Let me try for that

Comment: Two very basic things you could've done to troubleshoot the issue: 1. Remove pieces of the query until you isolate the SQL and the data that causes it; 2. Post the data types of the columns.